Fantasy movie about orphans and a creepy foster parent?
This movie is a fantasy kind of movie. I think it was made in the early 2000's, definitely no later than 2012.
I think it was about two, maybe three, abandoned children who are foster kids. They move from family to family, and eventually go they go a different guy's family. They turn out to be weird and crazy people.
There's this one guy that I think in the end the kids turn out to like. He sort of reminds me of the guy Johnny Depp from the movie charlie and the chocolate factory. You get Alice in wonderland kinda vibes. 

Most likely, you are thinking of the movie Lemony Snicket's A Series of Unfortunate Events.
The story is about a trio of rich orphans who are adopted by their uncle Olaf. Olaf is played by Jim Carey, and he does give off a very creepy Willy Wonka vibe. He does a lot of strange things (pretending to be other people, "faking" a marriage to the eldest girl, etc.)

